# chart.js Bars disappearing if values are the same

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have this code (borrowed and altered from W3Schools). The issue I am seeing on both Chrome and Edge is that some bars are disappearing, it seems to happen if subsequent values are the are the same as the first bar (e.g. Italy = 2 France = 2, Spain =2). Is the code wrong? Is there a solution? Is this a bug with Chart.js?

- UPDATE - after playing around a bit more, it seems more that it has an issue with the value '2'.

Here is a jsfiddle: [JS Fiddle disappearing bars](https://jsfiddle.net/7fo8ma6q/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
<body>

<canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>

<script>
const xValues = ["Italy", "France", "Spain", "USA"];
const yValues = [2, 2, 3, 14];
const barColors = ["red", "green","blue","orange","brown"];

new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "horizontalBar",
  data: {
    labels: xValues,
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: barColors,
      data: yValues
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {display: false},
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "World Wine Production 2018"
    }
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I find it interesting that it's only if there's more than one bar that's two. In the fiddle I got bars to be 1 and show and 3 and show... something/somehow it's considering 2 === 0... if you change the value to 2.1 it's showing 0.1... very peculiar... I'm sure this doesn't help much, but just thought I'd share the observations I noticed. HAHA. and you just edited it when I was typing this. 

Comment: Yeah, really odd.

Comment: I have investigated further and I have noticed that this code uses a very old version of charts.js. The current version is 4.4.1. I will update to that and see if the bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the graph carefully, you can see that the starting of x-axis value is 2.

[image]

Thus, when your value is 2, definitely it is not showing any bar as `2 === 2`, it does not exceed the min x-axis.

You have to overwrite the min x-axis value with `options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.min`. Reference: [Min Max Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/cartesian/category.html#min-max-configuration)

```
new Chart("myChart", {
  ...,
  options: {
    legend: {display: false},
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "World Wine Production 2018"
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

[image]

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qpnt6d?file=index.html)

For **Chart.JS v4**, you need to configure the `Chart` instance as below:

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar', 
  data: {
    labels: xValues,
    datasets: [
      {
        backgroundColor: barColors,
        data: yValues,
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: { display: false },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'World Wine Production 2018',
      },
    },
    indexAxis: 'y',
    scales: {
      y: {
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Reference: [Horizontal Bar Chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/horizontal.html)